# Why does this 'findstr' command not function as expected?

Tags: command-line, findstr

I use the command-line program 'findstr' frequently as I write software.  It helps me quickly locate all the files that contain a specific string in a set of subdirectories.  It is a lot faster to use 'findstr' than anything else in a lot of cases.  Today I ran into an issue where I wanted to find the string **">**, so I ran this command (what I considered to be a fairly typical escaped string):

```
findstr /sic:"\">" *
```

And got back this cryptic error message:  "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect."

Changing it to:

```
findstr /sic:'\">' *
```

Works properly.  Why did I need to use single quotes instead of double quotes?  I've run hundreds (maybe thousands?) of findstr commands before where I've escaped double quotes inside a double quote wrapper without any issue.  What makes this particular search string so different?

Comment: what OS are you using?

Comment: Windows 7.  Plain ol' Command Prompt (i.e. no PowerShell).

Comment: I'll check it out, but why not use PS?

Comment: The tools of the basic Command Prompt are generally sufficient for my needs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two levels of processing going on here - first `cmd.exe` is parsing the command line to determine if redirection, etc needs to happen, and then after that, `findstr` gets the remaining command line and does its own parsing according to its own rules (in practice, usually the same for various programs).

This [MSDN blog post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/twistylittlepassagesallalike/everyone-quotes-command-line-arguments-the-wrong-way) goes into some detail on the subject.

It seems to me that, since `>` is a `cmd.exe` metacharacter, what you need is the `cmd.exe` escape character, which happens to be `^`.  For example, this command works for me:

```
findstr /sic:"\"^>" *
```

Comment: This works fine.

Comment: +1 for the link to the extensive MSDN blog post.  Marking as the answer because this works.

Answer (score 4):

The character `>` is used for redirection and generally needs to be escaped with a caret if part of a literal string. Encapsulating the string in quotes will prevent metacharacters from being parsed and eliminates the need for escaping. That's why both `echo ">"` and `echo ^>` will print an actual greater than-sign instead of trying to redirect the output.

The second occurence of double quotes always marks the end of a literal string. It cannot be escaped, because the caret would not be parsed as a metacharacter; it is in between quotes. As a result, both `echo "">"` and `echo "^">"` will try to redirect the output, in this case to an invalid file.

In your first line, `findstr /sic:"\">" *`, the second double quotes are interpreted as the end of a literal string. The next character indicates a redirected output. The succeeding filename is indeed invalid; the error thrown is hardly cryptic. The remainder of the intended argument isn't even visible to the findstr-command, which only gets to execute `/sic:"\"`. If you want to stick to double quotes, the following syntax would behave as intended: `findstr /sic:""^>" *`.

Comment: `findstr /sic:""^>" *` does *not* work in Win7! Did you try it yourself?

Comment: How does the command behave on your system? I indeed tried it myself, on a Windows 7 machine and can confirm it does work.

Comment: Win7 x64, created a bunch of text files, a few had **">** in them while the rest didn't. Ran your command and just got a blinking cursor at the next line, as if it was waiting for input. I could type whatever I wanted, press Enter multiple times, but the only way back to the cmd prompt was via Ctrl+C/Break. No output at all.